# Calculating the percentage of one columns' values when another column is equal to a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

```
df <- data.frame(dive=factor(sample(c("dive1","dive2", "dive3"),20,replace=TRUE)),speed=runif(20))
> df
    dive      speed   Drift
1  dive1 0.80668490    TRUE
2  dive1 0.53349584    FALSE
3  dive2 0.07571784    TRUE
4  dive2 0.39518628    TRUE
5  dive1 0.84557955    TRUE
6  dive1 0.69121443    FALSE
7  dive1 0.38124950    TRUE
8  dive2 0.22536126    FALSE
9  dive1 0.04704750    FALSE
10 dive2 0.93561651    TRUE
```

Suppose I have a data frame of this form with a third column named "Drift" where the row values are either "TRUE" or "FALSE". How would I go about working out the percentage of rows equal to TRUE when "dive" equals a specific value. I.e. when dive==1 what percentage of the "drift" column is "TRUE"?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
df$Drift <- c(T,F)
sapply(split(df, df$dive), function(x) sum(x$Drift) / nrow(x) * 100 ) 
   dive1    dive2    dive3 
57.14286 42.85714 50.00000
```

Comment: Thanks this helps alot. Suppose I wanted to chsange the values in the "drift" column from TRUE's and FALSES to 0's and 1's...Do you have any idea how to go about doing that?
@jmsigner

Comment: apologies for being abit ignorant but what exactly does the "function(x)" argument do? @jmsigner

Comment: you pass a `list` of `data.frames` to `sapply`. Then you want to apply on each of the `data.frames` a `function`. The this case `function(x) sum(x$Drift) / nrow(x) * 100`. Hope this hleps, otherwise also have a look at `?sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set.seed(1)
df$Drift<-sample(c(T,F),20,replace=T)

sapply(split(df,df$dive),function(x){mean(x$Drift)})

> sapply(split(df,df$dive),function(x){mean(x$Drift)})
    dive1     dive2     dive3 
0.0000000 0.7500000 0.2727273
```

multiple the mean by 100 if you want percentage